# Authorisation when using the BigQuery API clients

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-bigquery, google-api-client

I have some data in BigQuery. I want to be able to query this data dynamically using a webpage with user inputs and controls. For example, a user may select some options from a drop down which would then go on to construct an SQL query that I send off in a REST request to the BigQuery API.

I am trying to work out how to simplify and or remove the authorisation needed to do these requests with the API. I do not want the user to have to sign in using their google account to authorise the API request - this site will be internally facing and access will already have been controlled through the Identity Aware Proxy on GCP. The issue seems to be that the method in the BQ API that i want to use (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query) needs authorisation scopes that I have to get through making the user login.

I am obviously already providing an API key and a Client ID for the request - why is the user login authorisation needed also?

```
<script>
var results;

  function authenticate() {
    return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
        .signIn({scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform.read-only"})
        .then(function() { console.log("Sign-in successful"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error signing in", err); });
  }
  function loadClient() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey("KEY");
    return gapi.client.load("https://content.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/bigquery/v2/rest")
        .then(function() { console.log("GAPI client loaded for API"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err); });
  }


  // Make sure the client is loaded and sign-in is complete before calling this method.
  function execute() {
    return gapi.client.bigquery.jobs.query({
      "projectId": "PROJECT-ID",
      "prettyPrint": true,
      "alt": "json",
      "resource": {
        "query": "SELECT * FROM `TABLE` where Division = 'ERLT Local (Majors)' LIMIT 100",
        "location": "europe-west2",
        "useLegacySql": false,
        "kind": "bigquery#queryRequest"
      }
    })
        .then(function(response) {
                var results = response.result.rows;
                console.log(results);
              },
              function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
  }
  gapi.load("client:auth2", function() {
    gapi.auth2.init({client_id: "CLIENT-ID.apps.googleusercontent.com"});
  });
</script>


<button onclick="authenticate().then(loadClient)">authorize and load</button>
<button onclick="execute()">execute</button>
```

As shown above, the user has to currently click on the authorize and load button before executing the query. How can I remove this step?

Comment: The Client ID does not provide authorization. This is used to set up an OAuth Flow which allows the user to login and generate OAuth tokens.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to be able to query this data dynamically using a webpage with user inputs and controls.

The desired functionality can be built around a webserver that accesses BQ using GCP service account. The account can be created via UI or using the command:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts create <sa-name> --display-name "<sa-name>" --description "Service account for BQ read-only access"
```

Then give the service account the permission to run jobs:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding <project-name> --member=serviceAccount:<sa-name>@<project-name>.iam.gserviceaccount.com --role roles/bigquery.jobUser
```

Replace the placeholders:
`<sa-name>` - replace with service account name,
`<project-name>` - replace with the project name.

Note the service account will need an additional permission to read the dataset.

This [solution](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-bigquery) allows to embed a parameterised query into a webserver. End users use a browser to optionally set query parameters, run the query and retrieve the results. I'm the author.

> I do not want the user to have to sign in using their google account

Users do not have to have GCP accounts. The webserver uses a service account.

> For example, a user may select some options from a drop down which would then go on to construct an SQL query

This is what the solution does. However due to cost and security considerations the end users are only allowed to construct the `WHERE` clause of the query. You can modify the code to have several SQL queries and then a dropdown would allow to pick up which query to use, another dropdown could set some query options etc.